# Tab-content not showing up

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with tabs that show content for two data-target(no problem in that). I've added a script which automatically changes tab after 5 sec. Tab changes but the tab-content doesn't show up. I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJmoWK)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var timeInterval, currnetIndex = 1;
            tabCount = 5;
            var tabContentObj = $('.tab-content');
            changeTabIndex();
            timeInterval = setInterval(function () { changeTabIndex(); }, 4 * 1000);

            function changeTabIndex() {
                if (currnetIndex > tabCount) {
                    currnetIndex = 1;
                }
                tabContentObj.hide();
                $('ul#myTab').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
                var currentAncorObj = $('ul#myTab').find('li a').eq(currnetIndex - 1);
                currentAncorObj.parent().addClass('active');
                $(currentAncorObj.attr('href')).show();
                currnetIndex++;
    
            };

            $('#myTab li').mouseenter(function () {
                clearInterval(timeInterval);
            }).mouseleave(function () {
                timeInterval = setInterval(function () { changeTabIndex(); }, 4 * 1000);
            });

            $('#myTab li a').click(function () {
                tabContentObj.hide();
                $('ul#myTab').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
                var currentAncorObj = $(this);
                currnetIndex = $('ul#myTab').find('li a').index($(this)) + 1;
                currentAncorObj.parent().addClass('active');
                $(currentAncorObj.attr('href')).show();
                currnetIndex++;

                //return false;
            });
        });
```

```css
.how-it-works {
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.board .nav-tabs {
 position: relative;
 margin: 40px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.board > div.board-inner > .nav-tabs {
 border: none;
}
p.narrow{
 width: 60%;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
.liner{
 height: 2px;
 background: #ddd;
 position: absolute;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 50%;
 z-index: 1;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
 color: #555555;
 cursor: default;
 border: 0;
 border-bottom-color: transparent;
 outline: 0;
}
span.round-tabs{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 line-height: 70px;
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 100px;
 background: white;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px;
}
span.round-tabs.one{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}
li.active span.round-tabs.one, li.active span.round-tabs.two, li.active span.round-tabs.three, li.active span.round-tabs.four, li.active span.round-tabs.five{
 background: #36ABE7 !important;
 border: 2px solid #2AC7CC;
 color: #fff;
}

span.round-tabs,.two{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}
span.round-tabs,.three{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}
span.round-tabs,.four{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}
span.round-tabs,.five{
 border: 2px solid #ddd;
 color: #ddd;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a.span.round-tabs{
 background: #fafafa;
}
.nav-tabs > li{
 width: 20%;
}
.nav-tabs > li a{
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border-radius: 100%;
 padding: 0;
}

.nav-tabs > li a:hover{
 background: transparent;
}
.tab-pane{
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 50px;
}
.btn-outline-rounded{
 padding: 10px 40px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
.btn.green{
 background-color: #69cb95;
 color: #fff;
}
@media(max-width: 585px){
 .board{
  width: 90%;
  height: auto !important;
 }
 span.round-tabs{
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
 }
 .tab-content.head{
  font-size:20px;
 }
 .nav-tabs > li a{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
 }
 li.active:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
 }
 .btn-outline-rounded{
  padding: 12px 20px;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "third-layer">
   <h1 class = "home-title" data-aos = "fade-right"><b>Our Services</b></h1>
   <section  class="section how-it-works" id="how-it-works">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="how-it-works-heading">
       <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="home" data-aos = "fade-left">
          <h2 class="section-title">Service Title 1</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="profile">
          <h2 class="section-title">Service Title 2</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="prototyping">
          <h2 class="section-title">Service Title 3</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="uidesign">
          <h2 class="section-title">Service Title 4</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="doner">
          <h2 class="section-title">Service Title 5</h2>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 board">
       
       <div class="board-inner" data-aos = "flip-up">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
         <div class="liner"></div>
         <li>
          <a href="#home" data-target="#home, #home1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="User Experience">
         <span class="round-tabs one">
           <i class="icon icon-profile-male"></i>
         </span>
          </a></li>

         <li><a href="#profile" data-target="#profile, #profile1" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Sketch">
        <span class="round-tabs two">
         <i class="icon icon-pencil"></i>
        </span>
         </a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#prototyping" data-target="#prototyping, #prototyping1" aria-controls="prototyping" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Prototyping">
        <span class="round-tabs three">
          <i class="icon icon-layers"></i>
        </span> </a>
         </li>

         <li><a href="#uidesign" data-target="#uidesign, #uidesign1" aria-controls="uidesign" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="UI Design">
         <span class="round-tabs four">
           <i class="icon icon-aperture"></i>
         </span>
         </a></li>

         <li><a href="#doner" data-target="#doner, #doner1" aria-controls="doner" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="Development">
         <span class="round-tabs five">
           <i class="icon icon-tools-2"></i>
         </span> </a>
         </li>

        </ul></div>

       <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="home1">

         <div class = "container">
          <div class = "row">
           <div class = "col-sm-6 board-container" data-aos="flip-up">
            <div class="boardd" style = "height:300px;"></div>
           </div>
           <div class = "col-sm-6 second-layer-list" style = "padding:40px;" data-aos = "fade-left">
            <font size = "4"><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget viverra sem. Curabitur lobortis bibendum odio ac varius. Ut non felis varius, viverra nibh vel, luctus neque. Nullam eget ante a felis lacinia convallis. Vestibulum varius metus sit amet aliquam convallis. Pellentesque vel venenatis justo. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.</center></font>
            <p class="text-center">
             <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-rounded blue" style = "background-color:#36ABE7;" data-aos="fade-left"> Know More <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>

         
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile1" data-aos="flip-up">
         <div class = "container">
          <div class = "row">
           <div class = "col-sm-6 board-container" data-aos="flip-up">
            <div class="boardd" style = "height:300px;"></div>
           </div>
           <div class = "col-sm-6 second-layer-list" style = "padding:40px;" data-aos = "fade-left">
            <font size = "4"><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget viverra sem. Curabitur lobortis bibendum odio ac varius. Ut non felis varius, viverra nibh vel, luctus neque. Nullam eget ante a felis lacinia convallis. Vestibulum varius metus sit amet aliquam convallis. Pellentesque vel venenatis justo. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.</center></font>
            <p class="text-center">
             <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-rounded blue"  data-aos="fade-left"> Know More <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="prototyping1" data-aos="flip-up">
         <div class = "container">
          <div class = "row">
           <div class = "col-sm-6 board-container" data-aos="flip-up">
            <div class="boardd" style = "height:300px;"></div>
           </div>
           <div class = "col-sm-6 second-layer-list" style = "padding:40px;" data-aos = "fade-left">
            <font size = "4"><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget viverra sem. Curabitur lobortis bibendum odio ac varius. Ut non felis varius, viverra nibh vel, luctus neque. Nullam eget ante a felis lacinia convallis. Vestibulum varius metus sit amet aliquam convallis. Pellentesque vel venenatis justo. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.</center></font>
            <p class="text-center">
             <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-rounded blue"  data-aos="fade-left"> Know More <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="uidesign1" data-aos="flip-up">
         <div class = "row">
           <div class = "col-sm-6 board-container" data-aos="flip-up">
            <div class="boardd" style = "height:300px;"></div>
           </div>
           <div class = "col-sm-6 second-layer-list" style = "padding:40px;" data-aos = "fade-left">
            <font size = "4"><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget viverra sem. Curabitur lobortis bibendum odio ac varius. Ut non felis varius, viverra nibh vel, luctus neque. Nullam eget ante a felis lacinia convallis. Vestibulum varius metus sit amet aliquam convallis. Pellentesque vel venenatis justo. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.</center></font>
            <p class="text-center">
             <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-rounded blue"  data-aos="fade-left"> Know More <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="doner1" data-aos="flip-up">
         <div class = "container">
          <div class = "row">
           <div class = "col-sm-6 board-container" data-aos="flip-up">
            <div class="boardd" style = "height:300px;"></div>
           </div>
           <div class = "col-sm-6 second-layer-list" style = "padding:40px;" data-aos = "fade-left">
            <font size = "4"><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget viverra sem. Curabitur lobortis bibendum odio ac varius. Ut non felis varius, viverra nibh vel, luctus neque. Nullam eget ante a felis lacinia convallis. Vestibulum varius metus sit amet aliquam convallis. Pellentesque vel venenatis justo. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus. Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.Vestibulum finibus rhoncus urna quis dapibus.</center></font>
            <p class="text-center">
             <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-rounded blue"  data-aos="fade-left"> Know More <span style="margin-left:10px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></a>
            </p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
```

Please look at the codepen. Snippet have some problem.
[1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJmoWK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in jQuery

it should be like this

```
var tabContentObj = $('.tab-content .tab-pane');
```

it was

```
var tabContentObj = $('.tab-content');
```

You were hiding whole `tab-content` div You have to only hide `tab-pane` div

**EDIT**

**Replace this line**

```
$(currentAncorObj.attr('href')).show();
```

**With this**

```
$(currentAncorObj.attr('data-target')).show().addClass("in");
```

before this you only show `href` elements you have to show both element which are in `data-target` attribute and also for have add class `in`.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgxJOK)**

Try with it hope it will helps you.

Comment: Yeah it's working.. but the second target should show too. The second target is not showing..

Comment: Thanks it works.. I'm getting a strange problem. The code is working on codepen but not on my webpage. Any idea what could effect it?

Comment: No.. Nothing in console... It worked.. mended the html code a bit. Thanks btw.. I was a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with working solution https://jsfiddle.net/L64s4bxh/2/

```
var tabContentObj = $('.tab-pane');

tabContentObj.hide().removeClass('in');

$(currentAncorObj.attr('data-target')).show().addClass('in');
```